# Vue.JS and Sails.JS query params "where" clause

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sails.js, vue-resource, sails-mongo

I'm using a Vue Resource to send HTTP requests to my Sails.JS backend.

Everything is working fine, except the only problem is the `where` clause in Sails isn't implementing the way it should.

Here's my code:

**My Template:**

```
  <div class="content">
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search Users" v-model="search">
    <button v-on:click="searchUsers" class="add-btn search-btn"> <i class="fas fa-search"></i> </button>
    <div class="list">
      <ul class="lists-group">
        <template v-for="(user, index) in users">
          <router-link v-bind:to="'users/user/' + user.id" class="lists-item">{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</router-link>
        </template>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My Script**

```
  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        search : '',
        users: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      searchUsers: function() {
        this.$http.get('http://localhost:1337/users?firstName=' + this.search).then(result => {
          this.users = result.body;
        })
        if (!this.search) this.getAllUsers();
      },
      getAllUsers: function() {
        this.$http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/v1/users').then(users => {
          this.users = users.body.users;
        })
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/v1/users').then(users => {
        this.users = users.body.users;
      })
    }
  }
```

I tried to use a get request with `{ params : { where : { firstName : contains : this.search } } }` but it's still not working.

What's the best approach to send a query like this?

```
'http://localhost:1337/users?where={"firstName":{"contains":"UserName"}, "occupation": "doctor"}'
```

Comment: Why won't you do that through backend?

Comment: any idea how ? just an example at least

Comment: Try `{ params: { where: JSON.stringify({ firstName: { contains: this.search } }) } }`